# NestJs - Class-validator not returning full validation error object

Tags: node.js, typescript, validation, nestjs, class-validator

I am using class-validator in NestJS to create valdations like this:

```
export class LoginDTO {
@IsEmail()
@MinLength(4)
email: string;

@IsNotEmpty()
@MinLength(4)
password: string;
```

}

It works, but not as expected. The returned object looks like this :

```
{
"statusCode": 400,
"message": [
    "email must be longer than or equal to 4 characters",
    "email must be an email"
],
"error": "Bad Request"
```

}

While i want it to contain all the information like this :

```
{
    "statusCode": 400,
    [{
        target: /* post object */,
        property: "title",
        value: "Hello",
        constraints: {
        length: "$property must be longer than or equal to 10 characters"
    }]
    "error": "Bad Request"
}
```

How to do to return all the missing properties ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This was a breaking change in `Nestv7`. [From the migration guide](https://docs.nestjs.com/migration-guide#validation-errors-schema) when using the `ValidationPipe` you can pass an `exceptionFactory` property like this

```js
exceptionFactory: (errors) => new BadRequestException(errors),
```

and it should give you what you want.