# Include name inside error class-validator nest

Tags: nestjs, nodes, nest, class-validator

I would like to know if it is possible and how can I return the field name along with the validation error message.

Example:
"message": {
name: "Name is required",
username: "Username is required",
}

instead of:

"message": [
"Name is required",
"Username is required",
]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: +1 I'm also facing this issue, I feel like this should be basic functionality, but it's not clear at all how this is done

Answer (score 2):

This is answered in [NestJs - Class-validator not returning full validation error object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61954312/nestjs-class-validator-not-returning-full-validation-error-object)

You can add `exceptionFactory: (errors) => new BadRequestException(errors),`
When you construct your ValidationPipe to get a detailed error response that includes the field name

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure this is what you want.

```
const message : {name : string, username : string} = {name :'alex', username : 'halo'}
```

So if you type to '{name : string, username : string}' typescript will allow only object that have keys name and username.

Comment: This isn't what OP is asking.

when you use class-validator as per this guide: https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/validation#learn-more

validation errors are returned simple as an array of strings, so there is no way to know which errors are associated with which property.